# Call Javascript from inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Currently I am using three external JS file.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="http://example.com/jquery.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://example.com/js.cookie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I like to make all three JS file in one.

Do it possible. i create **aio.js** and inside **aio.js**

```
src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js";
src="http://example.com/jquery.cookie.js";
src="http://example.com/js.cookie.js";
```

And then i will add

```
<script src="http://example.com/aio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

> So the Single File aio.js call all the 3 files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the Live example..**

```js
var element1 = document.createElement("script");
element1.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element1);
console.log(element1)
```

**For you :**

Put this code in your `http://example.com/aio.js` file

```
window.onload = function() {
   var element1 = document.createElement("script");
   element1.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js";
   document.body.appendChild(element1);

   var element2 = document.createElement("script");
   element2.src = "http://example.com/jquery.cookie.js";
   document.body.appendChild(element2);

   var element3 = document.createElement("script");
   element3.src = "http://example.com/js.cookie.js";
   document.body.appendChild(element3);
}
```

And in your html file..

```
<script src="http://example.com/aio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: `element.src = https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js";

element.src = https://example.com/example.js";`

Like this i can add multiple ??

Comment: i know about it. 

Here is full screenshot http://prntscr.com/aynxcg

i added directly, i am not using like `<script src="http://example.com/aio.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` for now

Comment: Oops to make it work we need additionally `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` . if i am including it working fine but when i am not it is not working. 


Your correct. But i need a one like code and all other code all from External JS file.

Comment: Show me your code that you had written in your `aio.js` file

Comment: use `window.onload = function() { ///js append code }` as i used in the answer and you have script tags in your js file at line 17 and 19, remove them

Comment: Still not work buddy, Maybe i am unable to understand correctly, Can you please contact me on skype : rajeev-rrs , i am unable to make chat here because it need 4 reputations. 

I did and followed everything you mention but still unsuccessful